# How to transpose from math xy graph to canvas coords in js

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I want to draw an XY graph (say X and Y from -100 to +100)

using the HTML canvas and javascript.

Say I'm using a 500x500  how would I transpose to canvas coords?
I'll set the center using canvas.translate()...

I want to do something like the following:

```
var cn = $('#myCanvas')[0]
var dr = cn.getContext('2d')
xmin = -100; xmax = 100
ymin = -100  ymax = 100
canvasWidth = cn.width
canvasHeight = cn.height

cn.translate(cn.width/2, cn.height/2) // set 0,0 to center of canvas

trMoveTo(-20, 50)
trLineTo(70, -40)
stroke()

function trMoveTo(x, y) { moveTo (xtr(x), ytr(y)) }
function trLineTo(x, y) { lineTo (xtr(x), ytr(y)) }
function xtr(x) { return ???  }
function ytr(y) { return ???  }
```

The problem is causing me brain reversal convolutions :-(

Comment: `(x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) * canvasWidth` should do it for the `x-`axis and similarly for the `y-`axis...

Comment: I'm checking that out. Please see my edit with the canvas center...
I think with the two you are right. Why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: with the shifted center, the formula would be `(x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) * canvasWidth - canvasWidth/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking after is a linear transformation from range, e.g., `(xmin, xmax)` to `(cmin, cmax)` (`c` denotes here canvas coordinates). This can be directly described as:

```
c = (x - xmin)/(xmax - xmin)*(cmax - cmin) + cmin
```

This formula first rescales `x` to the range `[0,1]` and then maps this onto the canvas coordinates spanning the range `[cmin, cmax]`. In other words, one can check directly that the formula is linear (affine) and `xmin` maps to `cmin` while `xmax` maps to `cmax`.

In your particular case, `cmin` for the `x-`axis seems to be `-canvasWidth/2`, while `cmax = canvasWidth/2`, thus

```
c = (x - xmin)/(xmax - xmin)*canvasWidth - canvasWidth/2
```

Comment: sorry I'll get to this only tomorrow. Meanwhile here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pashute/5zqt24uL/